# "no such column: instaton_picture.content" from django admin page

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I added an ImageField called "content" to my model (for Picture in my app "instaton"), and the python validates, and the sql queries that it's supposed to be calling include

```
CREATE TABLE "instaton_picture" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "pub_date" datetime NOT NULL,
    "owner_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "instaton_user" ("id"),
    "content" varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

where content is obviously a column, at the very least.

However, when I try to access the "Picture" element from my admin page, it gives "no such column: instaton_picture.content"

I believe it's right, that the database does not include a column called content, but I'm not terribly familiar with checking columns, and therefore I may have done it incorrectly.

I'm also not familiar with django, and especially not with ImageFields, so anything I could be doing wrong, I'm probably doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by resetting

`python manage.py reset instaton`

`python manage.py syncdb`

I didn't have any data, but, to be clear, if you do this, you will destroy all of the data that has been placed in the databases for your app. Wasn't a problem for me. Might be a problem for you. This is probably bad, overall.